# May one get an electric tattoo for blood pressure monitoring?

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, parashas-kedoshim, tattoo

Researchers have recently [found a way to measure blood pressure via graphene e-tattoos](https://news.utexas.edu/2022/06/20/blood-pressure-e-tattoo-promises-continuous-mobile-monitoring/) on the skin.

Would one be Halachically allowed to get such a tattoo, or would this fall under the category of כתבת קעקע ([Kedoshim 19:28](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.28))? Would even healthy people be allowed to get such a tattoo?

Comment: https://medicalhalacha.org/2021/08/24/are-those-eyebrows-real/ and this article in Tradition Halakhic Issues Presented by Breast Cancer discusses medical tattoing as part of Chemo https://www.jstor.org/stable/23263919  but this article says that in Israel they don't tattoo https://www.jewishexponent.com/2013/06/13/they-provide-a-lifeline-for-orthodox-women/

Comment: Is a "graphene e-tattoo" actually a tattoo (ink/dye/pigment  placed into an incision)? Or is it an implant that is colloquially being referred to as a "tattoo"? From what I can tell no incision is made nor ink used, rather the devise is adhesed to the surface of the skin.

Comment: @Deuteronomy is right. 2. the prohibition is on the doer IIRC (Rambam), so if a gentile does it it's his problem :)

Comment: @AlBerko  אבל זה שכתבו בבשרו וקיעקעו בו--אינו חייב אלא אם סייע, כדי שיעשה מעשה; אבל אם לא עשה כלום, אינו לוקה. Assisting in the act also determines liability (H. AZ 12:11[15]). Paying and willfully positioning/submitting the body are forms of assistance.

Comment: https://now.northropgrumman.com/e-tattoos-are-futuristic-healthcare-wearables/ this is a "tattoo" in colloquial name only. There is no incision or ink, and it only stays on for a short time. There is no relation to the issurim involved in tattoos.

Comment: This is a question for a rov.